# how to use nvidia-docker to create service in docker swarm

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

How do use nvidia-docker to create service in swarm mode of docker operation. I am trying to train a tensorflow model in this swarm network to undergo distributed learning. I found that one way could be to run a swarm network of different containers in different machines and use GPU on each machine to undergo [distributed training](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed). If its not possible in swarm mode, Is there any possible way to accomplish the above task?

> docker service create --name tensorflow --network overnet saikishor/tfm:test
>   azt0tczwkxaqpkh9yaea4laq1
>
> Since --detach=false was not specified, tasks will be created in the background.
>
> In a future release, --detach=false will become the default

but under docker service ls, I have this

> ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                   PORTS
>
> uf6jgp3tm6dp        tensorflow          replicated          0/1                 saikishor/tfm:test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, nvidia-docker is not supporting docker swarm. So, there is no possibility now. We need to create an external network to plug them together.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible when the question is asked, but not now.

Since [nvidia-docker2](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Installation-(version-2.0)) released, a new docker container runtime, usually named as `nvidia`, is supported.
This enables `docker run --runtime nvidia ...` to access GPU like `nvidia-docker run ...`.
Besides, after the `dockerd` option `--default-runtime nvidia` is configured, tools like `docker-compose`, Docker Swarm and Kubernetes can use GPU too.

[image: nvidia-gpu-docker]

### Install

#### Debian-based distributions

```
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | \
  sudo apt-key add -
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
sudo apt-get update
```

#### RHEL-based distributions

```
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.repo | \
  sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/nvidia-docker.repo
```

### Config

```
{
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    },
    "default-runtime": "nvidia",
    ...
}
```